# How dangerous is AllowAmbiguousTypes when used with TypeApplications?

Tags: haskell, types, ambiguous-call

How dangerous is the [`AllowAmbiguousTypes`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ambiguous-types-and-the-ambiguity-check) extension when used with the [`TypeApplications`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications) extension?

The GHC manual gives the following example of an ambiguous type:

```
class C a

f :: C a => Int
f = 3
```

This fails to compile when not using `AllowAmbiguousTypes` with the following message:

```
file.hs:8:6: error:
    • Could not deduce (C a0)
      from the context: C a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   f :: forall a. C a => Int
        at file.hs:8:6-15
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘f’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature: f :: C a => Int
  |
8 | f :: C a => Int
  |      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

With `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, it compiles correctly.

However, the following example fails to compile even with `AllowAmbiguousTypes`:

```
class C a

f :: C a => Int
f = 3

g :: C a => Int
g = f
```

It gives the following error when trying to compile it:

```
file.hs:12:5: error:
    • Could not deduce (C a0) arising from a use of ‘f’
      from the context: C a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   g :: forall a. C a => Int
        at file.hs:11:1-15
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: f
      In an equation for ‘g’: g = f
   |
12 | g = f
   |     ^
```

This can be written by enabling `TypeApplications` and writing it like the following:

```
class C a

f :: C a => Int
f = 3

g :: forall a. C a => Int
g = f @a
```

---

`AllowAmbiguousTypes` sounds scary, but based on the description in the GHC manual, it seems pretty benign, especially when used with `TypeApplications`.

It's not like `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is going to cause runtime errors, right?

This combination of `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` also seems to be used in some pretty popular packages, like [constraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.10/docs/src/Data-Constraint-Nat.html).

Comment: `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is completely “safe”, in the sense that it is perfectly sound, will not make the compiler diverge, and cannot lead to runtime errors, it was just mostly useless prior to the introduction of `TypeApplications`. The combination of the two is a perfectly reasonable thing.

Comment: This question is inspired by an answer I received to another question that used both `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` to good effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49671162/3040129.

Comment: I woulnd't mind if they both were turned on by default -- actually, I'd like that very much. Without them, we need additional `proxy a` arguments, which look hack-ish to me: why should I pass a runtime value which carries no information, only to tell the compiler that I want to use type `a`? That should be a compile-time argument, and now it can be if we use `foo @ a`. Ambiguous types are very good, once you have type applications. There is no downside to them, now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alexis King nailed it in her comment; it deserves to be elevated to the level of an answer.

> `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is completely safe, in the sense that it is perfectly sound, will not make the compiler diverge, and cannot lead to runtime errors. It was just mostly useless prior to the introduction of `TypeApplications`. The combination of the two is a perfectly reasonable thing.